# Using FindAll instead of Find

Tags: c#, lambda, find, findall

I am working on a program that (among other things) will find any U.S. city by zipcode, or find any zipcode by city. I have zipcode and city information stored in a .csv, and I am successfully pulling that data in and storing it.

As you can see from the below code, right now I am finding the first `City` that a particular zipcode is related to (the last line of code):

```
class City
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}

private void btnConvert2City_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Boolean firstLoop = true;
        string dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        string path = dir + @"\zip_code_database_edited.csv";
        var open = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(path));

        List<City> cities = new List<City>();
        foreach (String s in File.ReadAllLines(path))
        {
            if (firstLoop)
            {
                firstLoop = false;
                continue;
            }

            City temp = new City();
            temp.ZipCode = int.Parse(s.Split(',')[0]);
            temp.Name = s.Split(',')[1];
            temp.State = s.Split(',')[2];
            cities.Add(temp);
        }

        txtCity.Text = cities
            .Find(s => s.ZipCode == Int32.Parse(txtZipcode.Text))
            .Name;
```

This method works great for returning a city, however when a user searches by a city, the program must return MANY zipcodes. Currently my code for this process is as follows:

```
txtZipcode.Text = cities
    .Find(s => (s.Name == txtCity.Text.Split(',')[0]))
    .ZipCode
    .ToString();
```

Being new to C#, I figured I could change `cities.Find` to `cities.FindAll`. When I do this though, it will not allow me to include `.ZipCode`, and with `.ZipCode` removed, the program returns `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyConvert.formLookup+City]` in the textbox.

Are there any better ways that I can return all zipcodes associated to a particular city?

If it is helpful, the exact error I get if I do try to include `.ZipCode` is:

> Error 1   `'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyConvert.formLookup.City>'` does not contain a definition for 'ZipCode' and no extension method 'ZipCode' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Also, no reason to call `s.Split(',')` three times, just save the result in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
var sought = txtCity.Text.Split(',')[0];
string.Join(",", cities.FindAll( s => s.Name == sought ).Select(zi => zi.ZipCode.ToString()));
```

Comment: This works beautifully. Thanks. For reference, why doesn't `FindAll` work with `.ZipCode` like `Find` does?

Comment: Because FindAll returns a List http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Since, you have multiple zipcodes now try converting to a list first -

```
txtZipcode.Text = String.Join(",", cities.FindAll(s => (s.Name == txtCity.Text.Split(',')[0])).Select(s=>s.Zipcode.ToString() ));
```

Comment: yea updated don't really need the select. I should go home, i think you beat me to it anyways :)

Comment: I wouldn't say that.  You have both essential pieces, the `Select` and the `Join`.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick responses. For this code, I am still getting the same error as before with the last `.ZipCode`.

Comment: If I could select two answers I would. Thanks for your help!